# Laravel display "string()" when retrieve from model

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel i do the follwing query:

```
$courses = Curs::where('gruppe', "=", "fredag-wills")->get();
```

When i run `$courses->gruppe` it will return **string(12) "fredag-wills"** instead for  **fredag-wills** why?

here is the `var_dump($courses);` result

```
   object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#244 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(15) {
      ["attributes":protected]=>
      array(12) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(2) "48"
        ["keyid"]=>
        string(33) "wills-fredag-1-souvkimjmvpqdwsckh"
        ["endtime"]=>
        string(8) "12:50:00"
        ["parallel"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["gruppe"]=>
        string(12) "fredag-wills"
        ["booked"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
```

Comment: that is the expected output of using [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). there are [other ways](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) to output data, and `var_dump` is generally reserved only for debugging.

Comment: `var_dump` is for debugging, it's just telling you each item is of type string

Comment: i know what is var_dump, i get the same result when i do for example $courses->gruppe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those string are just plotted by var_dump so you can see every variable type, if you don't want to see them while debugging, you can do this:

```
$courses = Curs::where('gruppe', "=", "fredag-wills")->get();

foreach($courses as $course)
{
   echo $course->keyid . '<br>';
}

die;
```

Comment: i did that and i get: string(33) "wills-fredag-1-souvkimjmvpqdwsckh"

Comment: i want to get only 'wills-fredag-1-souvkimjmvpqdwsckh' without the **string(33)**

Comment: If you use `echo $course->keyid . '<br>';`, you'll not see (string), or there's something else in your system doing this.

Comment: Are you sure you removed that var_dump() line from your code?